# NPSP Relationships Custom Fields

Tags: npsp

We are using the new non profit start pack 3.0 and we want to add a few custom fields to relationships.  What I'm trying to setup is that these custom fields work like status where they copy from the relationship to the reciprocal as its being created.

Is there a built in way to do this.  I have about half a dozen new fields.  I could write a trigger but a little worried about getting into conflicts with the build in NPSP relationships trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this would require a custom trigger.  However, Nonprofit Starter Pack 3 has a new way to handle triggers which should make it possible to plug your own trigger in at the right time in the process to minimize complications.  You can find documentation on Table Driven Trigger Management (TDTM) in the Nonprofit Starter Pack 3 here along with a video from its developer on how to write your own custom triggers:

https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Table-Driven-Trigger-Management-TDTM